# How to Compare two file in unix and merge file 1 and 2 which includes both matching and non matching data

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

Kindly let me know how to compare 2 files and merge both matching and non matching lines. I have checked all the answers provide previously but nothing suits my requirement.Please find the Sample data sets below

Contents of `file1.csv`:

```
J2D     TEXAS        43988
J2D     AUSTIN       21305
J2D     CUPERTINO    378563
J2D     BELGIUM      569632
J2D     UK            0
J2D     US            8
J2D     INDIA         75321
```

Contents of `file2.csv`:

```
J2D     TEXAS        25463
J2D     AUSTIN       5986
J2D     CUPERTINO    0234
J2D     BELGIUM      123468
J2D     UK            5874
J2D     US            2365
J2D     IRAQ          8982
```

I have tried below command but it is not working in my scenario:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next;}{print $0 "    " ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA")}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Output:

```
J2D     TEXAS        43988    25463
J2D     AUSTIN       21305    5986
J2D     CUPERTINO    378563    0234
J2D     BELGIUM      569632    123468
J2D     UK            0        5874
J2D     US            8        2365
J2D     INDIA         75321    NA
```

In the above result, you can see "IRAQ" from `file2.csv` is missing.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next;}{print $0 "    " ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA")}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Output:

```
J2D     TEXAS        25463    43988
J2D     AUSTIN       5986    21305
J2D     CUPERTINO    0234    378563
J2D     BELGIUM      123468    569632
J2D     UK            5874    0
J2D     US            2365    8
J2D     IRAQ          8982    NA
```

In the above result you can see "INDIA" from `file1.csv` is missing

Below is the expected output. kindly help me to get the desired output

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
J2D     TEXAS      43988      25463
J2D     AUSTIN     21305      5986
J2D     CUPERTINO  378563     0234
J2D     BELGIUM    569632     123468
J2D     UK          0         5874
J2D     US          8         2365
J2D     INDIA       75321     NA
J2D     IRAQ        NA        8982
```

Comment: format your question at first to make it readable

Comment: Hi Roman, I have formatted the question. Kindly help me in this

Comment: is it OK for you if the output would be sorted by the second field?

Comment: Yes it is fine to be sorted...One more thing the first 2 column is the key combination in my scenario..

Answer (score 0):

***paste*** + ***awk*** solution:

```
paste file1.csv file2.csv | awk '{ if($2==$5) { print $1,$2,$3,$6 }
      else { print $1,$2,$3,"NA","\n",$4,$5,"NA",$6 }}' | column -tx
```

The output:

```
J2D  TEXAS      43988   25463
J2D  AUSTIN     21305   5986
J2D  CUPERTINO  378563  0234
J2D  BELGIUM    569632  123468
J2D  UK         0       5874
J2D  US         8       2365
J2D  INDIA      75321   NA
J2D  IRAQ       NA      8982
```

---

***Details***:

- `paste file1.csv file2.csv` - merge lines of files
- `if($2==$5) { print $1,$2,$3,$6 }` - if files matched by the second column (`$5` field points to the *early* second column of `file2.csv`)
- `print $1,$2,$3,"NA","\n",$4,$5,"NA",$6` - print unmacthed lines as separate lines with `NA` in relative positions

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk     '{k=$1 FS $2} 
   NR==FNR {a[k]=$3; next} 
           {print $0, (k in a)?a[k]:"NA"; delete a[k]} 
       END {for(k in a) print k,"NA",a[k]}' file2 file1 | column -t

J2D  TEXAS      43988   25463
J2D  AUSTIN     21305   5986
J2D  CUPERTINO  378563  0234
J2D  BELGIUM    569632  123468
J2D  UK         0       5874
J2D  US         8       2365
J2D  INDIA      75321   NA
J2D  IRAQ       NA      8982
```